# Formik access previous value

Tags: reactjs, formik

What is the best approach of updating a **formik** field state based on its previous state? Similarly to what we have using the `setState` function of the `useState` hook.

```
const [state, setState] = useState();
setState((previousValue) => previousValue + 1);
```